# Issue Patching Order Amount with Breakdown - Paypal Checkout NET SDK

Tags: paypal, sdk, patch, checkout, orders

I am running into a snag trying to patch a PayPal order with updated totals.  I am using the PayPal Checkout-NET-SDK that they provide out on GitHub, but the sample documentation they have for Patch Order Sample is a bit too simplistic:
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/PatchOrderSample.cs

I am trying to update the following path:
*/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount"*

I've tried using a combination of setting the value as:

- A JSON string representing the AmountWithBreakdown object
- An AmountWithBreakdown object

When calling the API with an AmountWithBreakdown object assigned as the value, I am met with a .NET exception:

*Type 'PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.AmountWithBreakdown' with data contract name 'AmountWithBreakdown:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders%27) is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.*

Sample Function that builds the PATCH request:

```
 Private Function BuildPatchRequest() As List(Of Patch(Of Object))

        Dim patches = New List(Of Patch(Of Object)) From {
            New Patch(Of Object) With {
                .Op = "replace",
                .Path = "/intent",
                .Value = "CAPTURE"
            },
            New Patch(Of Object) With {
                .Op = "replace",
                .Path = "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
                .Value = New AmountWithBreakdown With {
                            .CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode,
                            .Value = Me.Order.Total.ToString("N2"),
                            .AmountBreakdown = New AmountBreakdown With {
                                .ItemTotal = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = Me.Order.SubTotal.ToString("N2")},
                                .TaxTotal = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = Me.Order.TaxTotal.ToString("N2")},
                                .Shipping = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = Me.Order.ShippingTotal.ToString("N2")},
                                .Discount = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = Me.Order.DiscountTotal.ToString("N2")},
                                .Handling = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = Me.Order.HandlingFeeTotal.ToString("N2")},
                                .Insurance = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = "0.00"},
                                .ShippingDiscount = New PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money With {.CurrencyCode = Me.Order.CurrencyCode, .Value = "0.00"}
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
        Return patches

End Function
```

All attempts at constructing the JSON manually as a string and assigning it to the value are met with the generic *INVALID_PARAMETER_SYNTAX* error response, despite the output passing JSON validation tools.

Has anyone had any success updating this datapoint with PayPal using this SDK?  My implementation is in VB but I have gotten the gist of implementing all other functionality with the SDK being sourced in C#.

Comment: "All attempts at constructing the JSON manually as a string and assigning it to the value are met with the generic INVALID_PARAMETER_SYNTAX error response, despite the output passing JSON validation tools." Log the raw request+response body for these attempts so we can see what is wrong about them.

Comment: Preston PHX, I tried patching the individual points in your original comment and was met with UNPATCHABLE remarks in the response.  I'll need to pull the full project source down and integrate with my project so I can capture the raw request--I am just getting back an object using the classes provided in the SDK at the moment.

Comment: So I took a look under the hood of the PayPalHttp-DotNet dependency that implements the Execute method of the HttpRequest object being built and it looks like it is serializing the object--so I am assuming the JSON string I am passing is just being parsed as a regular string as the value parmeter in the patch request object.

Reference: https://github.com/paypal/paypalhttp_dotnet/blob/master/PayPalHttp-Dotnet/HttpClient.cs

Comment: That would make sense, but we need to see the full request and response of your best test in order to advise on what may be wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue.

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.AmountWithBreakdown' with data contract name 'AmountWithBreakdown:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders%27) is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

The call never makes it to PayPal for a response because it is failing to serialize the request.  The only way I've been able to get it to work is by generating my own request without the SDK. This isn't production ready code. I was just testing to see if it would work if I crafted the request myself, and it does.

```
var ppe = PayPalClient.environment(productLine);

        var accessTokenClient = new HttpClient(ppe);
        var accessTokenRequest = new AccessTokenRequest(ppe, null);

        var accessTokenResponse = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var httpResponse = await accessTokenClient.Execute(accessTokenRequest);
            return httpResponse;
        }).Result;

        if (accessTokenResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Logger.Error("[PayPalRestService] Unable to get access token.");
            return null;
        }
        
        var accessToken = accessTokenResponse.Result<AccessToken>();

        var client = new RestClient(ppe.BaseUrl());
        client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken.Token}");


        var body = BuildUpdateTaxPatchRequest(cart, paypalOrder);
        var request = new RestRequest($"/v2/checkout/orders/{paypalOrder.Id}")
            .AddJsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));

        var response = client.Patch(request);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
        {
            return GetOrder(paypalOrder.Id, productLine);
        }




private static List<Patch<object>> BuildUpdateTaxPatchRequest(ICart cart, Order paypalOrder)
    {
        //Doc: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch

        var subtotal = $"{cart.GetSubTotal():N2}";
        var shipping = $"{cart.GetShippingTotal():N2}";
        var discount = $"{cart.GetOrderDiscountTotal():N2}";
        var tax = $"{cart.GetTaxTotal():N2}";
        var total = double.Parse(tax, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) + double.Parse(shipping, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) + double.Parse(subtotal, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) - double.Parse(discount, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        var strTotal = total.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));


        var updates = new AmountWithBreakdown()
        {
            CurrencyCode = paypalOrder.PurchaseUnits.First().AmountWithBreakdown.CurrencyCode,
            Value = strTotal,
            AmountBreakdown = new AmountBreakdown
            {
                ItemTotal = new Money
                {
                    CurrencyCode = cart.Currency.CurrencyCode,
                    Value = subtotal
                },
                Shipping = new Money
                {
                    CurrencyCode = cart.Currency.CurrencyCode,
                    Value = shipping
                },
                TaxTotal = new Money
                {
                    CurrencyCode = cart.Currency.CurrencyCode,
                    Value = tax
                },
            }
        };

        var patches = new List<Patch<object>>
        {
            new Patch<object>
            {
                Op= "replace",
                Path= "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
                Value = updates
            }
        };

        return patches;
    }
}
```

Comment: Scott, thanks for this--as an absolute fallback I may have to go this route.  I have an open support case with PayPal to see if they can't get one of the developers from the SDK project to look into this or not.  Their GitHub page doesn't have an issues section and they direct you to PayPal support, so I have hoping I can get some answers there.

Comment: I've asked on the support case with PayPal to pass this along to their SDK development team and referenced this question's URL.  Scott, marking your answer as correct as I was able to implement a similar approach using a .NET HttpWebRequest object and self-serializing the object returned BuildPatchRequest for the request body.  I'll update this again if I ever hear back that they've resolved the issue or addressed how to do this purely using their SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and I looked to PayPalHttp.HttpClient source code and found the solution that working for me. Maybe this would be helpful for you.

```
public async Task<UpdatePayPalV2CheckoutPaymentResponse> UpdatePayment(string orderId, decimal amount)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new OrdersPatchRequest<object>(orderId);

        // This doesn't work because DataContractSerializer.
        // request.RequestBody(BuildPatchRequest(amount));

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BuildPatchRequest(amount));
        request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        await CreatePayPalClient().Execute(request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new UpdatePayPalV2CheckoutPaymentResponse
        {
            Success = false,
            Message = e.Message
        };
    }

    return new UpdatePayPalV2CheckoutPaymentResponse
    {
        Success = true
    };
}

private static List<Patch<object>> BuildPatchRequest(decimal amount)
{
    var patches = new List<Patch<object>>
    {
        new Patch<object>
        {
            Op = "replace",
            Path = "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
            Value = new AmountWithBreakdown
            {
                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                Value = amount.ToString("F")
            }
        }
    };

    return patches;
}

private PayPalEnvironment CreatePayPalEnvironment()
{
    PayPalEnvironment environment;
    if (_orderProcessingConfiguration.PayPalCheckoutConfiguration.Sandbox)
    {
        environment = new SandboxEnvironment(
            _orderProcessingConfiguration.PayPalCheckoutConfiguration.ClientId,
            _orderProcessingConfiguration.PayPalCheckoutConfiguration.ClientSecret
            );
    }
    else
    {
        environment = new LiveEnvironment(
            _orderProcessingConfiguration.PayPalCheckoutConfiguration.ClientId,
            _orderProcessingConfiguration.PayPalCheckoutConfiguration.ClientSecret
            );
    }

    return environment;
}

private PayPalHttp.HttpClient CreatePayPalClient()
{
    return new PayPalHttpClient(CreatePayPalEnvironment());
}
```